# React get data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express

I have an express app and react, express connected to react with proxy.
I have added data to mongodb from express

```
var HeaderSection = require('../../models/sections/header_SC');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var headerSc = [
    new HeaderSection ({
        imagePath:
            '',
        title:
            'Odelia Revivo',
        description:
            '- Makeup Artist -',
        buttonText:
            'צרו קשר'
})];
```

How can I get this data from React?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but couldn't you just use `HeaderSection.find()` to fetch the data from the DB since you have the model required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HeaderSection.find({your query here}) to fetch the data from the MongoDB